# ASUS N751JK, bluetooth doesn't work, ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-17.04

Can't make my bluetooth work on Ubuntu.
[The toggle is active.But it means nothing. Since system is not reacting on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8sGx.png)

`rfkill list` output is normal:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`hciconfig -a` gives the following info

```
hci0:    Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 9C:D2:1E:0D:2F:B2  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 128:2
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:1160 acl:0 sco:0 events:62 errors:0
    TX bytes:742 acl:0 sco:0 commands:62 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

Typping of `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` results in:

```
Can't init device hci0: Invalid request code (56)
```

The output of `hcitool dev` command is empty:

```
Devices:
```

This is `hcitool scan` output

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

I seached for similar problems, checked their solutions if it works in my case, but failed - nothing has helped me. So I've decided to ask it here

There may be another usefull information which is not given here for now. But I don't know yet what should be provided in order to make the problem be solved easier.

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming Q&A. If you need help configuring devices in Ubuntu then try searching and asking at https://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Download the driver for the Mediatek MT7630E wireless card here

https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796

and execute the commands to compile and install the driver.

If wifi works after installing the driver but bluetooth doesn't, you should check "Readme.md" in driver file directory (/Downloads/MT7630E-release).

It worked for me in Linux Mint 18.3. Both wifi and bluetooth. But wifi only at 2.4GHz